# Custom Deserializer to map a String to a boolean value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am making an external call via RestTemplate as follows:

```
ResponseEntity<Response> response = template.exchange("some.endpoint.com", HttpMethod.POST, request, MyClass.class);
```

The API returns a boolean value in String format as follows: ("0" or "1")

```
{
    "some_lengthy_key_name" : "1"
}
```

I am trying to map this response to the following class.

```
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)
@Builder
public class MyClass{
    @JsonProperty("some_lengthy_key_name")
    private final boolean isValid;
}
```

It looks like Jackson doesn't entertain this and throws following error (understandable):

> Can not deserialize value of type boolean from String "1" only "true"
>   or "false" recognized.

I don't want to go down the route of capturing it as a String and then modifying value after. 
Instead prefer to go for the option of getting a custom deserialization going and went for the following:

```
public class Deserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Boolean> {
    @Override
    public Boolean deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException {
        return !"0".equals(parser.getText());
    }
}
```

I've now annotated the field in MyClass as follows:

```
@Getter
@JsonDeserialize(builder = MyClass.MyClassBuilder.class)
@Builder
public class MyClass{
    @JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("some_lengthy_key_name")
    private final boolean isValid
}
```

But unfortunately this is not working either and throwing same error. 
Could I get some advice as to what I am doing wrong with this custom deserialization? Thanks.

Comment: Try with Boolean instead of boolean

Comment: @CodeScale Doesn't make a diff with Boolean.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any custom deserializer for this, just override the property with custom setter method and then annotated that method with  `@JsonProperty`. Another note jackson uses `getters` and `setters` for serialization and deserialization so you cannot declare variables as `final`

```
@Getter
@Setter
class MyClass{

   private boolean isValid;

   @JsonProperty("some_lengthy_key_name")
   public void setIsValid(String value) {
      isValid = "1".equals(value);
   }
}
```

There is another way in jackson for deserializing using constructor to prevent immutability of object, check this for more [information](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialize-immutable-objects)

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
public class MyClass{

   private final boolean isValid;

   public MyClass(@JsonProperty("some_lengthy_key_name") String name) {
      this.isValid = "1".equals(name);
}
```

Comment: Apologies. In my attempt to make the code look concise, I missed on mentioning the objects uses builder thus using final. I've edited the question to include how am adding builder to the above class. Like your solution but I don't wanna move from using builder thus not gonna be able to use setters.

Comment: You can use `Builder` without declaring variables as `final` also, builder will work normally you can try @karvai

Comment: I've followed your suggestion, moving JsonProperty annotation to the setter method. No errors like before but the mapping is not happening. I know the value is supposed to be true but getting false instead which I believe is cos its being set to default. Plus also this solution now opens up a public method for setting which I was trying to avoid to keep it immutable. I am still circling towards a custom deserialisation to be honest.

Comment: try using that constructor approach @karvai

Comment: It might work now with a single, but expecting more fields to come in that response (slightly over 10) and gonna add more fields. I don't want to do a constructor initialisation for this. Sorry I don't mean to shoot down your suggestions. 

I've tinkered around and noticed that my above custom deserialisation works if MyClass doesn't use a builder + no class level @JsonDeserialize annotation and instead sticks to Get/Set. Wonder if there is a way around it to use the builder and still have the above custom deserialisation work.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use `final`, and use a `Boolean` type instead of `boolean`

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyClass{
    @JsonDeserialize(using = Deserializer.class)
    @JsonProperty("some_lengthy_key_name")
    private Boolean isValid; //<= You did not use final, and use Boolean type instead of boolean
}
```

Comment: Same error when using Boolean and with or without final.